# HapiJS - Static Files

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I am trying to create a plugin for serving my static files in HapiJS. My file structure is the following

```
|_ plugins
|  |_ assets
|    |_ assets.js
|    |_ package.json 
|  |_ views
|_ public
|  |_ css
|app.js
| config.json
| package.json
```

Within my plugins/assets/assets.js file I have the following code:

```
const Inert = require('inert');

exports.register = function(server, options, next) {

    server.register('inert');

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/{public}',
        handler: {
            directory: {path: '../../public'}
        }
    });

    next();
};

exports.register.attributes = {
    pkg: require('./package');
}
```

Within my config.json file (glue manifest):

```
{
  "server": {
    "app": {
      "slogan": "We push the web forward"
    }
  },
  "connections": [
    {
      "port": 3000,
      "labels": ["web-ui"]
    }
  ],
  "registrations": [
    {"plugin": "vision"},
    {"plugin": "inert"},
    {"plugin": "glue"},
    {"plugin": "./plugins/assets"}
  ]
}
```

And finally, in my app.js:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var Glue = require('glue');

var manifest = require('./config.json');

const options = {
    relativeTo: __dirname
};

Glue.compose(manifest, options, function (err, server) {
    server.start(function(err) {
        console.log('Server running');
    });
});
```

My question is this the correct way to serve static files using a plugins approach with glue? All the examples I have seen do not use a plugin approach and instead use the server.register() within the app.js file to serve the static files from the public directory.

Comment: Your approach is fine, if you want to serve assets and static files yourself. You're save with your configuration and approach, there's no need to immediately move all your assets to a CDN. During a later development stage, you can migrate to a CDN, but starting out it's totally fine to serve them yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way of serving static files from node is: don't.

A CDN is highly preferable:

- A CDN charges you per terabytes sent.
- A cloud instance charges you per uptime.

In a monthly basis, for a regular application, the difference between these are in the order of thousands of dollars.

In a development environment, in absence of a CDN, you can serve your files from a regular web server like nginx. It is also less work, since nginx comes packaged in most distros.

There are performance considerations for this as well, you want to keep your application servers as fast as possible.